# Why does drop down list in ListView in user control cause full page postback in page-level update panel?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, c#-4.0

I have the following scenario.  I have a page that hosts several user controls.  The user controls are all surrounded by a single update panel.  All user controls have a save button on them.  When the save buttons are clicked the page updates the update panel as expected.

Some of the user controls contain editable list views.  Whenever an action is taken on these list views, the Update Panel is NOT refreshed, but the whole page posts back.  How can I get these ListViews to also refresh the Update Panel?  I cannot post the code because of NDA.

There are no javascript errors on the page reported by either IE8 or Chrome.

Comment: Are your update panels functioning in automatic or conditional mode?

Comment: The update panels are in automatic mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check the autopostback property of the dropdownlist control, if the property is set to true it tries to postback every time the selection changes.

If this does not work for you, you may wish to try implementing manual update triggers in your controls code and setting the update panel to conditional, to firmly control when you want the panel to update.

Comment: The drop down list's auto post back is supposed to trigger the update panel if it reside in one.  Also, this is happening on ALL events of the ListViews, not just a drop down list included in one of the ListViews.